# Data format to test Spring Rest Services

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, maven

I am testing spring rest services, particularly POST method. 
Here is the code snippet of my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testrequest", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee e){
        String value = "id " + e.getId() + "firstName " + e.getFirstName() + "lastname " + e.getLastName();
        System.out.println(value);
        return value;
    }
```

Employee class:

```
public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Employee(int id,String firstName,String lastName){
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Employee() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

I have included dependency of jackson library in pom.xml as well 
 pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am testing the services using firefox poster plugin.
[image]

When I submit my request, I am getting Status: **415 Unsupported media type.** 
This is the error message I am getting:
*The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.*

Please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testrequest", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
```

**EDIT**

Maybe try adding:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

to your pom

Answer (score 0):

Try following

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@RequestMapping(value = "/testrequest", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON){

}

Note : Make sure that your implementation works properly. I haven't tested 'jackson-mapper-asl'.You can include following dependency for the implementation and test it.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I am trying to convert json to Java object, not sure how it works in resteasy, but in spring @RequestBody would have taken care.